# Jenkins - Build Periodically doesn't work

Tags: build, jenkins

I have googled several posts, but can't find anyone mentioning their build periodically not inspite of configuring the cron in right way.

I have the below setting for Build Periodically which I guess is correct, as I see the below comment. Still nothing happens. I have Jenkins 1.574 (latest stable build).

*"Would last have run at Friday, 8 August 2014 07:01:40 o'clock BST; would next run at Friday, 8 August 2014 07:16:40 o'clock BST."*

`# every fifteen minutes (perhaps at :07, :22, :37, :52)
H/15 * * * *"`

I have tried with several combinations like 15 * * * * / H * * * * / etc. But nothing seems to help. Can someone help me debugging and pointing me at right direction?

Thanks,
Raghu

Comment: Is the quote at the end in your above command a typo? H/15 * * * ***"**

Comment: Looking at the description, there does not seems to be any reason why it should not work. Screen shot of the build periodically section would be good.

Comment: Have you checked your jenkins server log(/var/log/jenkins/jenkins.log, depends on your OS)? Sometime Jenkins job would not build for some errors, e.g. server disk is full.

Comment: @Technext - yes, the quote was typo, it isnt there in Jenkins config.

Comment: @Waman - I am unable to post a pic, as I don't have enough reputation

Comment: @wbinglee - I have jenkins hosted as a Windows Service. Checked jenkins.err.log on the root jenkins folder. No clues about triggers there.

Comment: Have you waited enough time? `H` means a range of 0~59 in your case. you may change it to `H/2 * * * *` to verify.

Comment: Googling for this message gives vague indications that it might be caused by a Jenkins plugin conflict.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced same issue.
My Jenkins version 2.50 running on Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS.

In order to get it resolved just create new job ( Do not copy ) with same configuration.

I really don't know what was the issue, but this is the solution I found.